# Visual C++ 2010 express, empty registers window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assembly

I am using Visual C++ 2010 express on my Windows 7 64-bit PC and I am programming in assembly language. When I am in debug mode on a breakpoint, if I open the registers window, it is empty. The address-level debugging mode is enabled. Also, I tried on a Windows XP PC and it works. So it seems that Windows 7 64-bit is the problem... Does someone knows if there is a way to see the registers?

Comment: Did you check that anything is enabled at all? Right click in the window and make sure at least one set of registers is checked.

Comment: I did not know about that, I will try this tonight, I don't have my PC right now.

Comment: That's what you said PMF, nothing was checked. Sorry for this simple question! Thanks!